# hive hbase intregration issue

Tags: hive, hbase

As I was facing issue with Hadoop version (1.2.1) when trying to execute count(1) query in Hive (created on a table on HBase). So I have upgraded my hadoop version to 2.6.0

Now when I am getting the below error

```html
hive> create external table hive_hbase_table3 (key string, col11 string, col12 string, col21 string, col31 string) stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' with serdeproperties ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,col_fam1:col11, col_fam1:col12, col_fam2:col21, col_fam3:col31") tblproperties("hbase.table.name" = "table3");
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
```

Can anyone please let me know am I missing anything as of this up-gradation?

Comment: Did you upgrade your HBase and Hive too? Whats their versions?

Comment: upgraded Hbase not Hive. Hive version 0.14 and upgraded HBase version is 1.0.1

Comment: Could you post your `pom` file of your `$HIVE_HOME` in your question? (Hive is dependent on HBase, but you have upgraded only your HBase.)

Comment: As it was not working so I have upgraded hive version as well to 1.1.0 and now it is working. I think previously created auxlib folder in $HIVE_HOME was containing old HBase jar and that was causing the issue.